# Re-populating Dropdown Box On Submission AJAX PHP JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, mysqli

So I am having an issue with re-populating data into a dropdown box after the form is submitted with Ajax. This is to remove an object from the dropdown, the initial script works fine, its just getting the new data and populating. My PHP script builds a JSON array to output to Ajax for parsing but when I check the PHP script the only thing that returns is }.

PHP Code:

```
    $jasonData = "{";
include_once("../php_includes/db_connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orginfo";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);    
$id = $rows["id"];
$orgname = $rows["orgname"];
$orgphone = $rows["orgphone"];
$jasonData .= '"option'.$id.'":{ "id":"'.$id.'","orgname":"'.$orgname.'","orgphone":"'.$orgphone.'" },';
}
$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= "}";
echo $jsonData;
```

AJAX Code:

```
function getorgs(){
var getorgs = ajaxObj("POST", "engine.php");
    getorgs.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(getorgs) == true) {
            var remresponse = JSON.parse(getorgs.responseText);
            alert (remresponse);
        }
    }
    getorgs.send("getorgs");
}
```

I have been building this off of several tutorials kind of piece meal along with things I have already learned and am using. The current lack of sanitation is because of testing, want to make sure things are working and then add it in to narrow down any issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: It may not be a good practice to declare a variable (var getorgs) the same as other named function (getorgs()); furthermore, you might wanna learn to use http://tw2.php.net/json_encode, it's more straightforward to generate JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');// this line must reside on top (before any output)

$jasonData = array();
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, 'SELECT*FROM`orginfo`');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    array_push($jasonData, $row);
}
echo json_encode($jasonData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

mysqli_close($db_connect);
```

Let me know if the above doesn't work out!